# Reading from .txt file into 2D array separated by comma (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

everyone. I'm working on a language translator program, my first task is to create a 2D array of French and English words from a file of 1000 translations. The file looks something like this:

```
1000
bonjour,hello
oui,yes
non,no
merci,thanks
```

this is what I've tried:

```
string langArray[2][num];
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
        {
            inFile >> langArray[i][j];
            cout << langArray[i][j] << " " << endl;
        }
    }
```

but its storing the whole line and not the words separately, so I need to figure out how to store the French words on one line of the array and the English words in the second line without that pesky comma.

Comment: Use `std::getline()` with a `','` delimiter instead of `inFile >> `

Comment: @user4581301 asking on SO is typically my last resort, I keep finding people using vectors or people wanting to put things into 2D arrays that are separated by spaces rather than commas, which would be a lot easier but I can't modify the file

Comment: How to do that with a 2d array is a detail that's easy to extrapolate. If your problems tend more to appear how to manage the 2d array correctly, use a `std::vector<std::vector,string>>` instead, that will be way easier to handle. Also your code looks like you want to use a dictionary (aka. `std::map<string,string>`).

Comment: Here's the base of my reseach I've done, if that helps more: regarding specific cases: https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_deDE833DE833&sxsrf=ALeKk02BMF9ANRzRI4RTOt3GGoaCQxm9yQ%3A1603729729102&ei=QfmWX5TWBc3osAfpnbLgBg&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%22c%2B%2B%22+read+comma+separated+file&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%22c%2B%2B%22+read+comma+separated+file&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoECAAQR1C_hrABWMOzsAFgvL-wAWgAcAJ4AYAB1QGIAa4ZkgEGOS4xNS4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCMABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjU-sXm1tLsAhVNNOwKHemODGwQ4dUDCA0&uact=5

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm not allowed to use vectors or maps unfortunately, I should've specified that in the question. It would probably make this easier if I could.

Comment: So do as I recommended in my 1st comment, or aren't you allowed to use `std::getline()` as well? Your problem is that `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, std::string)`reads up to the 1st whitespace character met, and not considers a `','` as a delimiter.